# Examine the continuity of $f(x)=x^2+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+...+ \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}+....$ at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Examine the continuity of $$f(x)=x^2+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+...+ \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}+....$$ at $x=0$

I tried to solve the problem using $$\lim_{x \to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x \to0^-}f(x)=f(0)$$ and I got both limits to be $0$. I think there is an error somewhere since my book says it is discontinuous.

Can you help me out?

 Thankyou

Comment: It's a geometric series. You can calculate the sum explicitly.

Comment: Question has been edited. Sorry for ur inconvenience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dots imply an infinite series, then you can first consider
$$
g(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}
$$
that converges to
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}}=\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}
$$
whenever
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^2}<1
$$
that is, for all $x\ne0$.

Thus your function is
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1+x^2 &\text{if $x\ne0$}\\
0&\text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that it's a geometric series, as Haral Hanche-Olsen commented. You can write $f(x)$ as

$$f(x) = x^2 \frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=x^2\frac{(1+x^2)^{n+1}-1}{x^2(1+x^2)^{n}} = \frac{(1+x^2)^{n+1}-1}{(1+x^2)^{n}}$$

This function is continuous at $x=0$ in my sense...

Comment: I think it sould be $$f(x) = x^2 \frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n}}}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}$$

Comment: Put $n=1$ in your form. You then get $f(x) = x^2$. It must be with $n+1$ because you start with a power 0 of your common ratio, $x^2(1+x^2)^{-0} = 1.x^2$ at the beginning.

Comment: the sum of first term should be $x^2$ right? So wat is wrong?

Comment: GP is $ a , ar , ar^2 , ...$ so i dont see my observation wrong.

Comment: $$a+ar+ar^2+...+ar^{n-1} = a \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} r^k = a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r} $$ So if your sum goes to $n$, you have $$a\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: thnx i understood......+1